# Very low collision non-cryptographic hashing function

Tags: algorithm, hash, language-agnostic

I'm writing an application that uses hashing to speed up file comparisons. Basically I pre-hash file A, and then the app runs and matches files in a folder with previously hashed files. My current criteria for looking for a hash function are as follows:

- It should be fast enough that disk IO is the limiting factor. I'm currently using SHA-256 which works just fine but is way too heavy and makes my application CPU bound.
- Cryptography/security doesn't matter in this case, the user is inputting both files, so if they craft a hash collision intentionally, that's on them.
- Hash collisions should be avoided at almost all costs. I can compare files based on size, and their hash, but if both of those match the files are assumed to be equal. I know it's impossible guarantee this with any hash due to the compression of data, but something with the same sort of uniqueness guarantees as SHA-256 would be nice.
- File sizes range from 10bytes to 2GB
- A streaming algorithm would be nice, as I try to keep the memory usage of the application low, in other words I don't want to load the entire file into memory to hash it.
- Hash size doesn't matter, if I got all the above with 1024bit hashes, I'm completely okay with that.

So what's a good algorithm to use here, I'm using C# but I'm sure most algorithms are available on any platform. Like I said, I'm using SHA-256, but I'm sure there's something better.

Comment: I've had pretty good luck with the 128 bit version of MurmerHash_3 in settings like this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MurmurHash

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28660441/fast-hash-function-with-collision-possibility-near-sha-1

Comment: How many files are we talking about?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yann Collet's xxHash may be a good choice ([Home page](http://cyan4973.github.io/xxHash/), [GitHub](https://github.com/Cyan4973/xxHash))

> xxHash is an extremely fast non-cryptographic hash algorithm, working
>   at speeds close to RAM limits. It is proposed in two flavors, 32 and
>   64 bits.

At least 4 C# impelmentations are available (see home page).

I had excellent results with it in the past.

The Hash size is 32 or 64 bit, but [XXH3](http://fastcompression.blogspot.com/2019/03/presenting-xxh3.html) is in the making:

> XXH3 features a wide internal state of 512 bits, which makes it
>   suitable to generate a hash of up to 256 bit. For the time being, only
>   64-bit and 128-bit variants are exposed, but a similar recipe can be
>   used for a 256-bit variant if there is any need for it one day. All
>   variant feature same speed, since only the finalization stage is
>   different.

In general, the longer the hash, the slower its calculation. 64-bit hash is good enough for most practical purposes.

You can generate longer hashes by combining two hash functions (e.g. 128-bit XXH3 and 128-bit MurmurHash3).

Comment: Looks like a winner